# Nginx always get 404

Tags: regex, nginx, location, url-rewriting

I have two folders with files: /var/www/imagestest and /var/www/imagestest2. In folder 2 files can be stored as is or splitted by num. For example request uri /images/0/1.jpg file can be stored in /var/www/imagestest2/images/0/0/0/0/1.jpg. Regular expression is OK, but i cant configure nginx to work with all folders sometime, and always get 404 for rewrited uri.

File structure:

```
/var/www/imagestest2/images/2.jpg
/var/www/imagestest2/images/0/0/0/0/1.jpg
```

Requests:

As is:

```
curl -I imagestest.local/images/2.jpg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Expected to get file from /var/www/imagestest2/0/0/0/0/1.jpg:

```
curl -I imagestest.local/images/0/1.jpg #
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

As is in splitted dir:

```
curl -I imagestest.local/images/0/0/0/0/1.jpg
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name imagestest.local;
    root /var/www/imagestest/;

    set $other_dir "/var/www/imagestest2";

    location ~ / {
        try_files $uri @other_dir =404;
        error_page 404 = @rewrite;
    }

    #try files as is
    location @other_dir {
        root $other_dir;
    }

    #try for splitted
    location @rewrite {
        root $other_dir;
        rewrite "^/(.*)\/([0-9]{1,3})\/(.*)" "/$1/0/0/0/$2/$3" last; #1-3
    }
}
```

But if i will set site_dir and rewrite in server block - i'll get 200 OK for splitted, but cant get files from folder /var/www/imagestest/:

```
curl -I imagestest.local/images/0/1.jpg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name imagestest.local;
    root /var/www/imagestest2/;

    set $other_dir "/var/www/imagestest2";

    rewrite "^/(.*)\/([0-9]{1,3})\/(.*)" "/$1/0/0/0/$2/$3" last; #1-3
.....
```